# What does "vanishes except" mean in "If $f$ vanishes except on a set of measure zero, then $\int_Q f=0$"?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

What does the "vanishes except" mean here?

> Let $Q$ be a rectangle in $\mathbb{R^n}$; let $f:Q\to \mathbb{R}$; assume $f$ is integrable over $Q$.
>
> a) If $f$ *vanishes except* on a set of measure zero, then $\int_Q f=0$
>
> b) If $f$ is non-negative and if $\int_Q f=0$, then $f$ *vanishes except* on a set of measure zero.

Comment: This means that the set where f is not zero is a set of measure zero

Comment: It might be appropriate to put a comma after “vanishes”, to make the sentence make a little more sense?

Comment: @DaveNine The theorem is from Munkres's Analysis on Manifolds,page 96, Theorem 11.3.

Comment: No. A comma is not appropriate as this would indicate a parenthetical statement and the meaning is different if it is removed.

Comment: @DaveNine and there is no any comma on the book

Comment: @PaulChilds Yesss